# How do you check if an NSInteger is greater than another NSinteger?

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa, nsstring, nsinteger

I'm trying to write code that detects if an integer is greater than another integer. Is this possible?

Here is what i've done so far.

```
if (NumCorrect >> NumWrong) {
    btnCool.title = @"Awww";
}

else {
    btnCool.title = @"Cool!";
}
```

All its doing is going to the else

**EDIT:**

```
NSString *numCorrect = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",NumCorrect];
NSString *numWrong = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", NumWrong];
lblWrong.text = numWrong;
lblCorrect.text = numCorrect;
if (NumCorrect > NumWrong) { 
    btnCool.title = @"Awww"; 
} else { 
    btnCool.title = @"Cool!"; 
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should NSLog your numbers to be sure they're what you think they are.  (And be careful to not make the mistake of trying to compare the strings with `>`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use single `>`

```
if (NumCorrect > NumWrong) {
    btnCool.title = @"Awww";
} else {
    btnCool.title = @"Cool!";
}
```

Double `>>` is a bit shift operation. You shift every bit in the binary representation of your variable NumCorrect NumWrong amount of bytes to the right. In almost all cases this will return in a number other then 0, which will then treated as a `false` value and thus the else block is executed.

Comment: If i print the integers, one is greater than the other. The comparison isn't working though. Thoughts?

Comment: Are you comparing the correct variables? Post your real code in the question.

Comment: Well yes because when I convert them to strings and print them, one is clearly greater than the other. That is my real code :)

Comment: Also note, that variable names are supposed to start with lower case letters.

Comment: I will change that, but since it is printing properly, I dont think that it will change anything.

Comment: Well than NumCorrect is not greater than NumWrong and the else block is executed.

Comment: Are you sure you're not trying to see if they are actually not equal? That's done with the `!=` operator.

Comment: Hmm. Thats what I thought, so I put them in strings and it is greater. Really weird.

Comment: And yes, I'm making a test taking app where if the number of questions they got wrong is more than what they got right, it change the text of the done button to "Aww."

Comment: As I said, post your code, including the print statements and the resulting log

Comment: This is basically what it is.    `NSString *numCorrect = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",NumCorrect];
    NSString *numWrong = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", NumWrong];
    lblWrong.text = numWrong;
    lblCorrect.text = numCorrect;
    
    if (NumCorrect > NumWrong) {
        btnCool.title = @"Awww";
    }
    
    else {
        btnCool.title = @"Cool!";
    }`                                                                        What is being printed is "numcorrect" is "1" and numwrong is 2

Comment: Thanks for moving it to my question.

Comment: Please don't post code this long in the comments. It's unreadable. That's why I said add it to your question. Anyway, I edited it for you. `%d` is the specifier for `int` variables. Use `%ld` for `NSInteger`. What does the following print: `NSLog(@"NumCorrect=%ld, NumWrong=%ld", NumCorrect, NumWrong);`?

Comment: Sorry! It gives this `NumCorrect=0, NumWrong=2`

Comment: WOW! Thanks so much!! I was stupid! I just switched the "cool" and "aww". Sorry for wasting your time :)

Comment: No problem. For the future: it sometimes help just to start writing a question and using such simple log statements that help prove your point. Usually you'll just find the solution on your own on the way without even having to post the question.

Answer (score 0):

Almost perfect - just take off one of those `>`'s.  `>>` and `<<` are for "bit-shifting", a weird hold-over from the earliest days of programming.  You're not gonna use them much.  What you really want is `>` and `<`, which is for testing if numbers are greater than each other or less than each other.

In addition, you may remember from math class that ≥ and ≤ (greater-than-or-equal-to and less-than-or-equal-to) are useful operations as well.  Because there's no symbols for those on most keyboards, however, C and Xcode use `>=` and `<=` instead.

Finally, you may already know this, but to check if two numbers are exactly equal to each other you can use `==` (because `=` is used for setting the contents of variables).

Hope that's helpful!

Comment: Thanks that is helpful! But I still have the same issue as above. No clue whats going on.

Comment: Where are your `NumCorrect` and `NumWrong` (you should use lowercase, btw, upper is for class names) variables being set?

Comment: Hi. I know i just learned that here :) I posted my other code above.